# Where does nvidia-smi get its information from?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, drivers

Given how everything is a file in Linux, processes don't magically get their information out of nowhere. If you're seeing information without sudo, then that means there's a file somewhere in [sysfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs), [proc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), or [devfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#devfs) that can be accessed as a user. Otherwise it could also just be from the kernel ABI (syscalls) rather than a file, where information could also be gathered from functions like [ioctl()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ioctl) and [socket()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) if not other direct syscalls like [getcpu()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getcpu).

So with that in mind, I'm looking for the source files nvidia-smi reads for its information

In fact, I'd like to extend this further than Nvidia alone since nouveau, radeontop, AMDGPU, and whatever Intel uses, also have similar ways of getting such information that are untold for some reason...

Which files do these processes get their information from?

My ultimate goal is to read these files with [Conky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conky_%28software%29) and display graphs for them 16 times a second for every GPU in my system, just like I'm doing for my system CPU and RAM use.

Comment: Not everything is a file in Linux. That is a fairly convenient model for many user applications, via /proc and /sys. However, there are generally also diagnostic routes available for hardware monitoring and setup.

Comment: yeah that's where I wanted to briefly point out the ABI, since that's really the only other place where you can get info from things like `ioctl()` or `socket()`, including things like i2c and all that. :P

Answer (score 11):

You can find this out yourself, with a single command.

```
strace -o results.txt -e trace=openat nvidia-smi
```

will run `nvidia-smi` and create a list of every file it opens as `results.txt`.

You will find that it uses `libnvidia-ml.so.1`, which is the [NVIDIA Management Library](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml). After loading that library, `nvidia-smi` opens files like:

- `/dev/nvidia0`
- `/dev/nvidia-caps/nvidia-cap2`
- `/dev/nvidiactl`
- `/dev/nvidia-uvm`

You'll find that these device nodes don't produce any useful monitoring information for direct reading; no doubt the library is doing specific `ioctl(2)` system calls to those devices to get the information it needs. (You can confirm this with `strace -o results2.txt -e trace=openat,ioctl nvidia-smi`.)

If you wish to do some programming to get the information you want, you probably should read the [NVML API Reference Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/index.html) and use the `libnvidia-ml.so.1` library instead of trying to make raw `ioctl()` calls in your own code. You'll probably find almost everything you would want to monitor in real time in chapter 2.14, *Device Queries*.

However, there are some files that look like they might be directly readable:

- `/proc/driver/nvidia/capabilities/mig/config`
- `/proc/driver/nvidia/capabilities/mig/monitor`
- `/proc/driver/nvidia/params`

This gives us hope that `/proc/driver/nvidia/` and its sub-directories might be worth examining; alas, there's not much in there that would be worth real-time monitoring.

So, unfortunately it looks like it's not quite as easy as reading some files with Conky; if you aren't willing to do a bit of programming, might I suggest starting with processing the output of

```
nvidia-smi -q -d MEMORY,UTILIZATION,TEMPERATURE,VOLTAGE,POWER
```

or a similar command?

And I think running that kind of monitoring in a cycle of 16 times per second is a silly overkill unless you are troubleshooting a specific issue.

Comment: oh interesting, strace segfaulted for me, so I figured it was nvidia-smi's doing, thanks for letting me know that actually works

Comment: also 16 FPS gives me a graph with 3 seconds of sample history, unless I downscale the sample width... but anyways, the more samples I take, the more accurate the graph... of course I can only do so many samples since that uses a lot of CPU... heh

Comment: also thanks for the suggestion, but I do have an LUA library that'll let me use `ioctl()` in conky ;)

Comment: The NVIDIA ioctl numbers and data formats might be undocumented, so using them without the helper library can be a pain in the backside :-/ 
If you want to try it, you'll have my sympathy.

Comment: lol, it wouldn't be my first go at something like that, but much appreciated :)

Comment: @Tcll: Exactly, the CPU overhead of polling that frequently is significant.  The x-axis time-scale doesn't have to be 1 pixel per sample, you could scale to a 3-second window for any sample rate.  If this is something you leave running all the time, at least half a second between sample seems reasonable.  Having an option to crank up the resolution makes sense for when you're looking for short spikes in behaviour.  At least on a multi-core system there's hopefully a spare core most of the time, unless you're running a multi-threaded workload that keeps all cores busy.

Comment: @PeterCordes actually, the polling itself isn't all that bad, the kernel can handle more than 100 polls a second just fine, though yes fds are still pretty slow and would benefit better from direct syscalls (ioctl() and socket() are quite bloated however, but would still be better to use over fds)... no what actually uses a ton of CPU actually relates to Conky and LUA with cairo since I can't make things more efficient with OpenGL VBOs.

Comment: @Tcll: If you had some computational work that a core could be doing, even interrupting it 100x per second isn't great.  Disrupting out-of-order exec is still pretty minor at that rate, with 40M clocks between interruptions vs. an out-of-order window size of a few hundred uops.   But worse, context-switch to another process that does some stuff will evict some data from caches and disrupt branch prediction, making things slower for a while switching back.

Comment: @Tcll:  https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/osdi10/tech/full_papers/Soares.pdf measured that disruption just from running kernel code inside a system call, with reduced IPC (insns per cycle) for a while after returning to the interrupted process.  e.g. a couple percent degradation even with 500k instructions between `pwrite` system calls. (40M cycles is maybe like 80M instructions, but you're doing a full context switch which disrupts more, but looking at the numbers it's still minor.)
 Contention for memory bandwidth and PCIe traffic is still hopefully negligible at 100x per second, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd argue it depends on how it's done really... it's not the polling itself that harms it, but like you mentioned, clearing the caches could slow things down and all that... it's a matter of the care put into it to keep things fast, yeah that I agree with.

Comment: @Tcll: Hmm, if polling is cheaper than GUI updates, perhaps high-resolution mode could only update the GUI every 4, 8, or 10 samples, so you have more temporal resolution in the graphs while only doing the disruptive heavy lifting less frequently.  But each poll still takes a context-switch away from whatever a core could have been doing, so it's not free.  I wouldn't want it running on my system 24/7.  It also wastes a small amount of power when idle, stopping the core or whole package from going into a deeper sleep if it might otherwise have been able to.